# React - SafeAreaView not working for iPhone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iphone

My App has no color left and right from the notch, when using iPhone horizontal and when I refresh the site (move down then there is no color over the navbar).

I tried to fix this by

Anyone knows how to make area around notch same color as navbar and why SafeAreaView not working for me?

```
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';


function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Router>
        <ScrollToTop />
        <Header />
        <Pages />
        <Footer />
      </Router>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

SafeAreaView is designed to provide padding for notched devices and ensure that content does not overlap with the system's UI. However, it does not handle background color. To set the background color for the entire app, you need to add a style to the SafeAreaView component. Here's an example:

```
<SafeAreaView style={{ backgroundColor: 'your_color_here' }}>
  {/* Your app content */}
</SafeAreaView>
```

Replace 'your_color_here' with the desired color value.

Answer (score 0):

use the **react-native-safe-area-context** library like this :

```
import {SafeAreaView} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

function App() {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <Router>
                <ScrollToTop />
                <Header />
                <Pages />
                <Footer />
            </Router>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

export default App;
```